# Does CIContext memory leak still exist on iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, core-image

When using CIContext with an EAGLContext I get a huge memory leak on iOS 9.2. I've seen reports of this being solved on iOS 9.1 but I cannot confirm that. Has anyone successfully been able to remove the memory leak caused by CIContext drawImage, createCGImage and render on iOS 9.1 or later?

See this question on [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/97590#97590)

I've tested dropping EAGLContext by using MetalKit and MLKDevice. I've tested using different methods of CIContext like drawImage, createCGImage and render but nothing seem to work.

It is very clear that this is a bug as of iOS 9.2. Try it out your self by downloading the example app from Apple (see below) and then run the same project on a device with iOS 8.4, then on a device with iOS 9.2 and pay attention to the memory gauge in Xcode.

Download https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013109

Add this to the APLEAGLView.h:20

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CIContext* ciContext;
```

Replace APLEAGLView.m:118 with this

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
 _ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_context];
```

And finaly replace APLEAGLView.m:341-343 with this

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  

    @autoreleasepool  
    {  
        CIImage* sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];  
        CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, sourceImage, nil];  
        CIImage* filteredImage = filter.outputImage;  

        [_ciContext render:filteredImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];  
    }  

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle);
```